# "Can't play this video" using VideoView on Android Studio...tried many things and it still doesn't work

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

Hi I'm trying to play a 432x320 .mp4 video (which I've manually converted to .mp4 H.264 format) on an Android Studio application using a Relative Layout within a frame layout.  I keep getting a "Can't play this video error."

Here's what I have as an .xml file (note, I have many buttons/imagebuttons that I omitted from my post here because they're irrelevant and they take up a lot of space)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.kenneth.alphieii.AlphieII">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Robot"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/alphie_robot1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/mytexttester"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


...a bunch of buttons here including Yellowb0...this is not an error

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"

        android:layout_above="@+id/Yellowb0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />



</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have the actual video posted here and it can be easily downloaded...

!https://streamable.com/y01zy

And I have a picture of the current interface (note the videoview size needs to be adjusted)

[image]

I've tried a number of things such as...

```
 mVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.example.s3project/raw/" +
 R.raw.alphie_vidprompt);
 mVideoView.start();
```

and...

```
    String uriPath = "android.resource://" +
    "com.android.engineersdream.ed_video/" + R.raw.alphie_vidprompt;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

  mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

I haven't been able to get anything to work despite trying out suggestions made to people who've had a similar problem getting a videoview video to work.  Is there any other suggestion that I could be missing?  Is the format of my video improper?  Is there another easier method of playing videos on Android Studio? Thanks.

EDIT:
I tried copying the video .mp4 files to the SD Card as suggested and it still doesn't work.  I've placed these in the Android Manifest.xml file:
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Here's what I have for OnCreate...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphie_ii);
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    push = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.On);
    //imgButton.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
    final int[] mvids = new int[] { R.raw.alphie_vidprompt, R.raw.alphie_vidcorrect };
    for (int i = 0; i < mvids.length; i++) {
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Alphie";
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (dir.mkdirs() || dir.isDirectory()) {
                String str_song_name = i + ".mp4";
                CopyRAWtoSDCard(mvids[i], path + File.separator + str_song_name);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void CopyRAWtoSDCard(int id, String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    try {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And here's what I used to call the video...

```
 Uri vidFile = Uri.parse(
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
 + "alphie/alphie_vidprompt");

    mVideoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);
    mVideoView.start();
```

I still get the same message "Can't play this video"
Though I still have plenty of things to learn, I still don't understand why copying a video to the SD card would be necessary.  I'd hope that it would be easy enough to run it from the res/raw directory.

Comment: Can you try copying the video to your device and linking to that path instead?

Comment: I'm actually using Android Emulator, and I'd like the video to be a part of the overall Gradle (and part of the app) ideally speaking, rather than separate from the app.

Comment: I meant change your app to use the sdcard for the URI, rather than the resources.

Comment: Make sure the device which you are using supports H264 format

Comment: With the same code, try playing .mp4 file. If it works,then there is no problem in your code. The problem may be in the way you converted.mp4 to H264 fromat

Comment: I've already done (converted to H264) this (as I've indicated in the post) using an online converter, my video file is in a link on my above post https://streamable.com/y01zy .  Is there a specific converter you would recommend that's guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give a wrong package name (`com.example.s3project` or `com.android.engineersdream.ed_video`). Your should be `com.example.kenneth.alphieii` or `com.example.kenneth`, given by your layout. But you should use package name from context, like:

```
getPackageName();
```

So in your case you should use

```
"android.resource://".concat(getPackageName()).concat("/raw/").concat(R.raw.alphie_vidprompt);
```